# `npm install` from sub directory of a Git repository

Tags: angular, git, npm, npm-install, angular-library

Greeting, I have created an angular library and I have built & pushed it into private repo in gitlab, now I need to consume it inside another project

so I have tried to import it using the following line in package.json

```
"my-core-lib": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:<username>/my-core-lib.git"
```

But that was downloaded the whole repo and put it inside node_modules including "dist" folder

I need to import the content of "dist" folder and not the whole repo something like:

```
"my-core-lib": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:<username>/my-core-lib.git/dist"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just push it to the npm registry and then install it from there?

Comment: @BrianRT Personally, I want to avoid cluttering my namespace (or god-forbid the global namespace) with one-off bug fix- and PR- packages

Answer (score 5):

If the package source is hosted on GitHub, you can use [GitPkg](https://gitpkg.vercel.app/) like this:

```bash
# using npm:
npm install https://gitpkg.now.sh/<user>/<project>/<subdir>?<commit-ish>
# using yarn:
yarn add https://gitpkg.now.sh/<user>/<project>/<subdir>?<commit-ish>
```

There is a nice wizard-like form at their [site](https://gitpkg.vercel.app/) that helps build the URL, and the command to install it.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. 1) GitPkg is a life saver! 2) That NPM doesn't support this out-of-box is incredibly disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

If you build a custom library, and the entry point is not in the root of its Git repository, then you merely need to perform some post-install processing - to move your source to the proper place.

Optionally, you can also apply file filter, so that `npm` copies from the repository just the files/directories you need in the module.

Edit `package.json` and add two lines: `files` and `scripts` -> `postinstall`, so that the file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-custom-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "files": ["dist"],
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "mv ./dist/* ./ && rmdir ./dist"
  }
}
```

GL!

Comment: Pay attention with postinstall ... it does work great BUT if you add a package in the dev library itself it will also run postinstall and whatever commands you have there. Lesson learned the hard way ... :D

Comment: This is kinda weird. In fact postinstall is run twice, which is why `mv` and `rmdir` will fail if the package is installed as a dependency into some project. See: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5897